# Typescript bracket notation issue in react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to store and update form input changes, so I added a form state:

```js
const [form, setForm] = useState({
 user: '',
 email: '',
 password: '',
});
```

I then created a function for handling form changes:

```js
 const handleFormChange = (event: { target: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement }) => {
 const updatedForm: updatedForm = { ...form };
 updatedForm[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
 setForm(updatedForm);
};
```

I also added an interface for the `updatedForm` type:

```js
interface updatedForm {
 [key: string]: string;
}
```

But now there is an error:

> Argument of type 'updatedForm' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ user: string; email: string; password: string; }>'.
>
> Type 'updatedForm' is missing the following properties from type '{ user: string; email: string; password: string; }': user, email, password

What's wrong, and is there a solution?

Comment: Instead of doing what you're doing you can do
const handleFormChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>  and get the props for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types aren't matching. A possible solution could be to create an interface for the form state (you could also cast it without creating an interface but it wouldn't be very clean):

```
interface updatedForm {
    [key: string]: string
}

interface IForm {
    user: string
    email: string
    password: string
}

const [form, setForm] = useState<IForm>({
    user: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
});

const handleFormChange = (event: { target: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement }) => {
    const updatedForm: updatedForm = { ...form };
    updatedForm[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setForm(updatedForm as IForm);
};
```

Or you could also destructure the `name` and `value` from `target` like this and also use destructuring for the `setForm` assignment:

```
const handleFormChange = (event: { target: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement }) => {
    const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
    setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });
};
```

In this case there would be no need for the `updatedForm` interface.

Edit: to properly cast the `updatedForm` type to the `IForm` type it's necessary to cast them in the following way:

```
setForm(updatedForm as unknown as IForm)
```

Because of [double assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#double-assertion)

Comment: I did that but got another error, then I added as unknown before as IForm, and it fixed: `setForm(updatedForm as unknown as IForm)`